# On Catalan's complete solution to the equation $T^2=U^2+V^2+W^2$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations, sums-of-squares

Catalan proved the following: If $t,u,v,w$ are coprime integers such that
\begin{equation*}
 t^2 = u^2 + v^2 + w^2,
\end{equation*}
then there exist integers $\alpha,\beta,\gamma,\delta$ such that
\begin{align*}
 t &= \alpha^2 + \beta^2 + \gamma^2 + \delta^2,  \\
 u &= \alpha^2 + \beta^2 - \gamma^2 - \delta^2, \\
 v &= 2(\alpha\gamma +\beta\delta), \\
 w &= 2(\alpha\delta-\beta\gamma).
\end{align*}

My question is this: If $t,u,v,w$ are such that there are no **positive** integer solutions (*i.e.*, at least one of $\alpha, \beta,\gamma,\delta$ must be negative), what could be proven about $t,u,v,w$ without any additional information being given?

Note: Obviously, the signs don’t affect the magnitude of $t$ or $u$ (because they are sums of squares) — but signs **do** affect the [relative?] magnitude of $v$ and $w$.

EXAMPLE: I have been unable to find positive integers $\alpha,\beta,\gamma,\delta$ such that $(t,u,v,w)=(13,3,12,4)$; but allowing negative numbers, one possible solution [of four that I've found] is $(\alpha,\beta,\gamma,\delta)=(2,2,-1,2)$.

Comment: complete discussion, including inequalities, in the MAA Monthly, volume 69, number 5, May, 1962, pages 360-365, by Robert Spira. Title is The Diophantine Equation $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = m^2.$ He says the first satisfactory proof of completeness is due to Dickson, 1920. What is the Catalan reference?

Comment: Bull. Acad. Roy. Belgique, (3), __9__ (1885) p. 531
Might have been "noted" and not [adequately] proven?

Comment: @WillJagy: I don't see in that reference where he deals with negative $\alpha,\beta,\gamma,\delta$? There is a section with restrictions, but they’re all restricted to positive values in order to obtain the desired result [that solutions are unique]…

Comment: Well, he says there was an incomplete proof in a 1915 book by Carmichael.  Wait a minute, he says volume 2 of Dickson's History, which I have...

Comment: page 265, Lebesgue stated it, evidently no proof. Catalan on page 266, a few things. appears between them, Lebesgue and Catalan proved various special cases. Any more precise statement would involve reading the original references.   I do not doubt your question is different from Spira's inequalities, but he has something. Possibly useful.